# how to get data from each li using jquery each function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have a unordered list and each list element have "data-id" attribute, the idea is that using JQuery's each function iterate through each list element and get the "data-id" value and dynamically assign the position, ie to make a item slider that slides one item at a time.
but on each the value of data I'm getting is **"1"**, ie its taking value from the first element only,
how do I fix it??

**HTML**

```
<div class="explore_matches">
   <p>Recent Matches</p>
   <ul class="clearfix item-slider">
       <li data-id="1" ><span>1</span></li>
       <li data-id="2" ><span>2</span></li>
       <li data-id="3" ><span>3</span></li>
       <li data-id="4" ><span>4</span></li>
       <li data-id="5" "><span>5</span></li>
       <li data-id="6" "><span>6</span></li>
       <li data-id="7" "><span>7</span></li>
       <li data-id="8" "><span>8</span></li>
    </ul>
    <button name="pre">Pre</button>
    <button name="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var item_width = $('.item-slider').width();
var item_margin = (item_width-600)/5;
var items = $('ul.item-slider>li');

$.each(items,function(index){

    var pos = $('.item-slider > li').data('id') * 150;
    if(index === 0)     
        $(this).css("left", pos);
    else
        $(this).css("left", pos + index * item_margin);
    console.log(pos);
})
```

Comment: Where are you accessing the `data-id` attribute in your code?

Comment: oops, since that wasn't working i'm using the index of each function, wait let me edit, the question

Comment: Something wrong in your HTML. Remove extra quotes from 5th li.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace

```
var pos = $('.item-slider > li').data('id') * 150;
```

with

```
var pos = $(this).data('id') * 150;
```

Comment: Awesome, such simple thing hard to notice, thanks man Nikolay,

Comment: take care with this - I believe that using the .data() method - the value is cached and may cause altered functionalty - I would suggest .attr('data-id'); as  @Mayank Pandey has suggested

Comment: @gavgrif - What makes you think it is cached?

Comment: i used to use .data('x') a lot but was reading in SO about the different aspects of data attributes and people smarter than me pointed it put - so now I use .attr('data-x'); as the preferred method of getting / seeting the data attribute value.

Comment: Could you please share a link to that discussion?

Comment: maybe it wasn't SO but try this http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5 or this https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-data-caching-of-data-attributes

Comment: Well, it seems the OP is safe enough if he doesn't start changing the attribute value afterwards, which I'm quite sure of since it is id-something. Otherwise he may switch to `var pos = $(this).attr('data-id') * 150;`.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var data = $(this).attr('data-id');   // it will give 1,2,3 and so on
    //do stuff to each
});
```

Comment: thanks man, but please check the accepted answer, I think that is the right way to use data since there is a data function.

Comment: be careful with accepting simplistic answers @River CR Phoenix there is often a subtle reason why one option is better than another.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the elements attribute using `getAttribute` method

```js
var item_width = $('.item-slider').width();
var item_margin = (item_width-600)/5;
var items = $('ul.item-slider>li');

$.each(items,function(index, node){
    var pos = index * 150;
    alert(node.getAttribute('data-id'));
    if(index === 0)     
        $(this).css("left", pos);
    else
        $(this).css("left", pos + index * item_margin);
    console.log(pos);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="explore_matches">
   <p>Recent Matches</p>
   <ul class="clearfix item-slider">
       <li data-id="1" ><span>1</span></li>
       <li data-id="2" ><span>2</span></li>
       <li data-id="3" ><span>3</span></li>
       <li data-id="4" ><span>4</span></li>
       <li data-id="5" "><span>5</span></li>
       <li data-id="6" "><span>6</span></li>
       <li data-id="7" "><span>7</span></li>
       <li data-id="8" "><span>8</span></li>
    </ul>
    <button name="pre">Pre</button>
    <button name="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, this works, but is there any way to get the data value from each li??